# In CSS, is performance increased by using the :is() pseudo-class?

Tags: css, performance, browser, css-selectors, gecko

Are current releases (mid-2023) of web browser engines (Gecko, WebKit, Blink for Firefox, Safari, Chromium web browsers) smart enough to realize that they can internally gain efficiency by combining together CSS code such as the following?

```
foo baz {
  color: #000;
}
bar baz {
  color: #000;
}
foo boo {
  color: #000;
}
bar boo {
  color: #000;
}
```

Or does it lead to better performance to write the above CSS code as follows?

```
:is(foo, bar) :is(baz, boo) {
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I think you can intuit that this will have essentially zero impact on performance.  The CSS engine is going to compile both of those into internal tables, and the tables are very likely going to be identical.

Comment: @TimRoberts If you or I wrote the engines that would likely be true.  But, for better or worse, we didn't!  Of course, if we wrote all the code for every browser, they would be perfectly efficient and would never crash, right? ;)

Comment: Those engines have been tweaked by teams of bright people for 25 years.  There is no unpicked low hanging fruit.  And honestly, unless you have a hundred thousand elements, the compute time will be overwhelmed by the network overhead.

Comment: @TimRoberts With respect, I think you're a bit confused. The :is() pseudo-class has not been around for anywhere close to 25 years, and the Blink engine is only 10 years old. If you research recent browser optimizations, you can see that there have been many recent changes.

Comment: I'm actually wondering why you believe the second would be more efficient.  The first is certainly more typing, but it's probably implemented as a hashed table lookup, whereas the second requires evaluating an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't not worry about performance while you are using CSS, because there are no obvious way (and need) to optimize it. What can you do is to use minifiers for CSS to reduce the size of file (if it is big) to reduce the page load time, but, again, think twice do you really need it and do you have problems with performance in your code now. If not, you have nothing to worry about. Otherwise you should refactor and optimize the places, which could cause unwanted time delays (as a JavaScript code, especially if it contains loops in loops and AJAX/Socket requests, or as a backend with lots of queries to database per one AJAX/Socket request), and the CSS almost always is not this place (of course, you can use superset of CSS which supports loops or use really lots of animations (hundreds of them) and in case you really want to slow down your code with current tool, you could obtain this behaviour, but it is challenging task and literally impossible in real projects).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Do you have evidence to support what you wrote?

Comment: @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket Most of the time you waiting while the page is loading takes loading HTML, CSS and JS, but not calculating the loaded styles on the client. To prove that, you can create few hundreds `div` containers and give them lots of different styles (which will take as many lines of code as possible). Then measure page loading time. After that use online minifier to minify your HTML/CSS and measure the time again, you will see a difference